# Why the result is like this?

Tags: reactjs

first question： 
Printed twice 'run'

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  console.log("run");
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      look
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

second question：
first click: 1,1
second click: 1,1,1
third click: 1,1,1,1,1
...

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  console.log("run");
  const [count, setCount] = useState([1]);
  const push = () => {
    setCount((count) => {
      count.push(1)
      return [...count]
    })
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count.toString()}</p>
      <button onClick={push}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

sorry, I don't understand? Can help me?

Comment: looks like expected behavior.... what were you expecting the output to be?

Comment: What kind of behaviour do you expect?

Comment: For the first question, I want to know when is the timing of printing twice

Comment: For the second question, I think it should be added every time

Comment: Sorry, my question is a little elementary school

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using `StrictMode`.

In `StrictMode` React [tries to detect unexpected side effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) by invoking some of your lifecycle methods twice only in dev mode. It makes it clear why `run` is printed twice in the first code snippet, in the second one you actually have a side effect in the `setCount` callback: you're modifying the `count` array. Instead of modifying the existing array, you should return a new one from the callback:

```
  const push = () => {
    setCount((count) => {
      return [...count, 1];
    })
  }
```